# Efficient nested regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

Is there an efficient and general way to match regular expressions as well as compositions based on them ?

For instance, if I want matches for each of those 3 strings: `"I like"`, `"cats"`, and `"I like .* cats"`, I can obviously make 3 separate queries.

Is there a more efficient way to do this (preferably in python) ?

Comment: Do you mean how to apply several regexes to the same text? Like `|` operator?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian several nested regexes in the same text. it seems inefficient to search for "I like" and "I like .* cats" separately...

Answer (score 1):

```
patterns = ["I like", "cats", "I like .* cats"]

for stuff in patterns:
    re.search(r'%s' % stuff, string_to_search, flags)
```

More efficient, stops at the first match ordering patterns by lenght:

```
for stuff in sorted(patterns,key = len):
    if re.search(r'%s' % stuff, string_to_search):
        break
```

Comment: That's better than my suggestion

Comment: This produces the results I want, but I wonder if there's a more efficient way, for instance avoiding the duplicate work of searching for "I like" when "I like .* cats" exists...

Comment: this pretty much depends on your matching strings.In the example above you can cycle with `for stuff in sorted(patterns,key = len):` and `break` after the first match.

Comment: If your patterns can be non related (example: `["I like", "cats", "hey", "I like .* cats", "hey dude"]` ) you need to write a sorting function that moves at the end of the list the smaller patterns.